# change system settings from android widget

Tags: android, settings, system, widget

I have a widget that changes some system settings, but it will not take right away.  It seems like I need to refresh the system settings for it to take.  How do you change some system settings from a widget that take instantly?

when my widget is pressed it goes to an activity with a blank background to change the system settings. one of the settings that are changed is the display brightness. this is the code i use to change the display brightness. once i change the settings i call the finish function to exit the activity so i am not stuck there after the settings are changed.  One thing i did notice is that if i didnt exit the activity the settings did change, but i was stuck in the activity.  its when i added the class.this.finish(); to exit the activity that the settings don't change.

```
android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, brightness); // 0-255 
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
lp.screenBrightness = brightness / 255.0f;
getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

Comment: Could you add a few more paragraphs on what you think "system settings" are and how you are changing them, or perhaps some source code demonstrating your problem? That'll make it much easier to help you. Thanks!

Comment: I put some more info in my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

found the answer, I was exiting the activity to quickly. for some reason i need to delay my exit for a few hundred milliseconds so the changes take place.

Comment: On which devices did you test this?

Answer (score 1):

The real way to adjust the brightness for the system is not visible in the SDK. The code you have is as good as it gets -- the setting will take effect on next reboot, the `screenBrightness` setting will affect the current activity.

Comment: yea, i found that that screenbrightness will change the setting for the current activity, but when i exit out the activity the system setting for the brightness will then work. but the issue is when i do this for a widget, it doesn't take when i use the finish(); command right after i change the settings.

Comment: Screen brightness changes just may not work well from an app widget.

Comment: Is it possible to change the screen brightness through reflection or other tricks without having the device_power permission?